# Iterating a mathematical function over a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration, calculation

I am trying to do calculations on a dataframe. The datarframe has 65 columns.

```
id_1 Id_2   sum_id1 Sum_id2 Price   Cal_1   Cal_2
1    5      15      35      2       -68     -60
2    6      15      35      3       -99     -87
3    7      15      35      4       -128    -112
4    8      15      35      5       -155    -135
5    9      15      35      6       -180    -156
```

The columns from ID_1 to Price are given. The calculation is done as (ID_1-SumID_1)*Price. I have to iterate this for 60 columns. So I need a solution that iterates.

I have tried the method from Numpy but it is useful for one calculation. I have to loop it through over 60 columns.

Answer (score 2):

**What about a for loop using string replacements?**

```
# assuming there are 60 unique values
n = 60
for i in range(1, n+1):
    df[f'Cal_{i}'] = (df[f'Id_{i}'] - df[f'SumID_{i}']) * df['Price']
```

Comment: Yaakov the ID is just a float., 100098 etc. But I can try this

Comment: I think this is the most natural, but you need to either do `range(1, n+1)` or do `i+1` in the format strings to deal with the id numbering starting at 1.

Comment: Also I am not sure about n, I have a program before this that creates the data frame which will change n every time.

Answer (score 1):

I am using `filter` and re-create the dataframe , then `concat` it back

```
s=(df.filter(like='Id').values-df.filter(like='Sum').values)*df.Price.values[:,None]
s=pd.DataFrame(s,columns=['Cal_'+str(x+1) for x in range(s.shape[1])],index=df.index)
df=pd.concat([df,s],axis=1)
df
   Id_1  Id_2  sum_id1  Sum_id2  Price  Cal_1  Cal_2
0     1     5       15       35      2    -68    -60
1     2     6       15       35      3    -99    -87
2     3     7       15       35      4   -128   -112
3     4     8       15       35      5   -155   -135
4     5     9       15       35      6   -180   -156
```

Comment: In my data frame, ID_1 is just an integar . I put ID_1 as an example.